# Find 5 rows with the largest column values

Tags: r, sorting, max

I have a very large data file, and my goal is to find 5 rows that have the 5 largest values in the V4 column, so I sorted the data, and got the largest values, and then using a logical expression tried to find the entire rows. The problem is that even though I can find the top 5 values, the logical expression only gives me 3 rows instead of 5.

```
> h<-head(sort.int(d$V4, decreasing=T), 5)
> h
[1] 65506 39681 32306 29028 27535
> d[d$V4==h,]
             V1   V2 V3    V4                            V5
373135  1504839 1990  1 27535 77963;4;21;3;49;64;13;113;7;6
1365437 2141627 2010  1 39681         8;258;236;39;86;28;58
1797593 1822695 1992  1 32306                             0
```

So, why I cannot find the corresponding rows for 65506, and 29028?
Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: that works, but the order will be lost!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `order()` function, it gives you directly what you would like:

```
d[order(d$V4,decreasing=T)[1:5],]
```